# Get “Could not create the Java virtual machine” error running StarTeam 2008 Release 2 client

Tags: jvm, starteam

Why didn't StarTeam 2008 Release 2 Client install correctly on my machine? Whenever I try to launch it, I get a “Could not create the Java virtual machine” error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than being a problem locating the Java Virtual Machine, as I’d previously thought, turns out it’s a memory allocation issue.

In StarTeamCP.stjava, the default option set is `-Xmx1024m`. My machine doesn’t have a gig of RAM to spare for a Java VM, hence the error.

By setting it to `-Xmx512m`, I was able to get up and running.

See also [my blog entry](http://neontapir.github.io/professional/2009/02/24/starteam-install-woes/) about this.