# Which Java Errors and Exceptions may (not) be thrown by "empty statements"?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm, virtual-machine, jls

**Which** subclass(es) of `java.lang.Throwable` may be thrown by an empty statement?

By the phrase "an empty statement", I'm **referring to** the "nothing", the "semi-colon", and the "semi-colons":

```
// ....
A(); B(); C();
try {
     // nothing
} catch (java.lang.Throwable e) {
     // which Throwable subclass might we see?
}
D(); E(); F();
try {
     ; // semi-colon
} catch (java.lang.Throwable e) {
     // which Throwable subclass might we see?
}
G(); H(); I();
try {
     ; ; ;;  ;;;;; ; ; ;;; ;; ;; ;; ;; ; ;; ; ;; // ... semi-colons
} catch (java.lang.Throwable e) {
     // which Throwable subclass might we see?
}
J(); K(); L();
// ....
```

**Which** subclasses of Throwable may be thrown between `A();` and `B();` or between `C();` and `D();` or between `F();` and `G();` or between `I();` and `J();`?

Or rather, **which** subclasses of Throwable are **guaranteed** **not** to appear between those statements?

---

[The ones I know so far](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27679158/632951) is the [`InternalError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InternalError.html), the [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), the [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html), and the [`UnknownError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnknownError.html).

Comment: Did you check the resulting bytecode?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead, You could read the question as "Which Java Errors and Exceptions may (not) be thrown **between** bytecodes?" It's not even the `null`, it's the "nothing".

Comment: Uh, apart from cricital `Error`s I don't see

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728866/no-throw-virtualmachineerror-guarantees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679158/whats-the-definition-of-during-the-operation-of-the-java-virtual-machine) you posted. I think I'll try to address both questions here.

Since you refer to the JVMS I'll assume that you're after a formal answer, and the formal answer is that your question(s) doesn't really make sense. :-)

Asking *how* the JVM will execute a snippet of Java source code is like asking a mathematician the *correct* way of computing 10+10. The mathematician will probably say something like "*how* to compute it is not defined". Similarly, the JLS that defines the meaning of the Java snippet does not go into specifics of *how* to execute it.

So, first let me formalize your question slightly: "Where in the *bytecode* (emitted by the reference implementation of `javac`) corresponding to the given Java snippets could `VirtualMachineErrors` occur?"

This question is arguably much simpler to answer. The [relevant section of the JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.3) says

> A Java Virtual Machine implementation throws an object that is an instance of a subclass of the class `VirtualMethodError` when an internal error or resource limitation prevents it from implementing the semantics described in this chapter. This specification cannot predict where internal errors or resource limitations may be encountered and does not mandate precisely when they can be reported.

Thus, the answer is: Between any two bytecode instructions.

Now to return to your original question: This snippet for instance

```
try {
     // nothing
} catch (java.lang.Throwable e) {
     // which Throwable subclass might we see?
}
```

is compiled to the empty program, which can't reasonably throw any exceptions.

---

Regarding your follow up question in a comment:

> Should JLS 11.1.3 be read as "subclasses of `Throwable` are guaranteed not to appear between bytecode unless it is a subclass of `VirtualMachineError`"?

Yes, you could put it like that. I would perhaps have worded it a bit differently: Any instruction can give rise to

- the exceptions specified by the [JVM Instruction set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html) for the instruction in question,
- any exception of type `VirtualMachineError`
- and no other exceptions

Comment: A program may require a fixed set of resources to run even if it's the empty program. So in the face of resource limitations when running the empty program, is the correct behavior (according to JVMS) to throw a `VirtualMethodError`?

Comment: Hmm.. I must say I can't figure out a formal answer to that. A JVM can probably throw a `VirtualMachineError` for an empty program. Curiously `javac` drops the whole try/catch block for a program containing `try { } catch (VirtualMachineError e) { ... }`, so either `javac` is not 100% formal in this regard, or there's something in the spec that I haven't understood.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will probably remove the code that contains "nothing" or empty statements from the bytecode. The equivalent in the bytecode would be exactly similar to:

```
// ....
A(); B(); C();

D(); E(); F();

G(); H(); I();

J(); K(); L();
// ....
```

Of course during the execution, any kind of unexpected `Error` (like `UnknownError`) could occur and it's normally not expected to handle it in your application.

The closest kind of exception that could occur *anywhere* (emphasized in order to possibly cover the time between two bytecode instructions) is [asynchronous exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.3):

> Most exceptions occur synchronously as a result of an action by the thread in which they occur, and at a point in the program that is specified to possibly result in such an exception. An *asynchronous exception* is, by contrast, an exception that can potentially occur at any point in the execution of a program.
>
> Asynchronous exceptions occur only as a result of:
>
> - An invocation of the (deprecated) `stop` method of class `Thread` or `ThreadGroup`.
>
>   The (deprecated) `stop` methods may be invoked by one thread to affect another thread or all the threads in a specified thread group. They are asynchronous because they may occur at any point in the execution of the other thread or threads.
> - An internal error or resource limitation in the Java Virtual Machine that prevents it from implementing the semantics of the Java programming language. In this case, the asynchronous exception that is thrown is an instance of a subclass of `VirtualMethodError`.

But again, there is no point to care about this type of exceptions (subclasses of `VirtualMethodError`) because they represent a serious error in the JVM execution. For example, it may be due to a manual interruption by the user using **Ctrl+C**. In this case, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Should JLS 11.1.3 be read as "subclasses of Throwable are **guaranteed** **not** to appear between bytecode unless it is a subclass of `VirtualMethodError`"?

Comment: @Pacerier I would read it as "unless it is an asynchronous exception" (there's another condition mentioned about asynchronous exceptions, which I've added to the quote)... And I would read it with a grain of salt as it doesn't explicitly address your question. On a different note, one point I missed that's worth mentioning is that we're assuming that the thread in question is not _blocked_.

Comment: It must have been a typo and should read `VirtualMachineError`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't execute any instruction then the VM is unlikely to request memory or run out of stack space for the current thread. As the other exceptions could be thrown because any kind of state in the VM is out of kilt, I guess you should always expect `InternalError` or `UnknownError` to occur. Hence you should not catch `Throwable` but `Exception` as it is unlikely you can recuperate from the error - unless you are creating your own framework maybe.

Comment: Does the JVMS guarantee that a random thread executing instructions cannot cause the other threads to throw errors even while they are not executing any instructions?

Comment: I very much doubt that that is an explicit rule, but I haven't seen any implementation that would throw such an error if you are not allocating any space. One thread asks for 2 Gi worth of `long[]` and this exception gets thrown on the other thread? Nah.